# How do I follow someone else's activity in Azure DevOps Boards?

Tags: azure-devops

I know how to review my own activity in Azure DevOps Boards via the Work Items Page - My Activity dropdown/pivot, but how do I review someone else's activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write a query to look at `Changed By` | `=` | `Person`. You can also search for `Changed By` | `Was Ever` | `person`

[image]

2. Use the Audit log under the Organisation settings.

[image]

There's a Microsoft article which describes how to use the audit, and how to filter it which can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page. You can also export audit data as CSV or JSON to integorate in another application.

3. Or, there's an activity feed extension you can install from the marketplace.

Comment: I've thought about Changed By, but that only reflects the latest change to the Work Item. So, you can have multiple people have activity on a work item in the last day (especially via discussions), but only the last person would show in a query result.  I will look for the extension you mentioned.

Comment: It looks like you were referring to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davesmits.VSTSActivityFeed.  It looks pretty inactive. It is a great idea, and a feature that ADO needs built in.  I installed it and tested it out, but it didn't support filtering by person. Also, I don't think it would perform well in a large project.

Comment: Does the person assign it to themselves and then update it? Some fields allow a `was ever` so you could use `assigned to` `was ever` person. Then filter from that list. Alternatively you'll need to use the API to query the database or warehouse. Changed by may also have a `was ever`, but I can't remember now.

Comment: Updated the answer, you can use `was ever` with `Changed By`.

Comment: Using `was ever` is a good tip. It is better than nothing, but they could have changed it 6 months ago, so it doesn't help me determine recent activity.  Also, you can't determine how many times they changed it or when. This is not really what I am looking for.

Comment: Then you need to make your question more specific. If you only want within last x days, add changed date and an appropriate date value.

Comment: I think asking for **activity** is pretty clear, especially when I gave an example of how I view my own activity.  If you can't tell the difference between 1 action and 1000+ actions, then I would argue that you aren't seeing activity. Your answer would definitely be accepted if the question was 'how do I see what items an individual ever changed?' I a have accepted your answer because I appreciate your time. Thanks

Comment: @successhawk I've added another option to the answer.

Comment: Audit logs do no have Boards information.  They are more related to Azure DevOps administration tasks.  The closest to Boards it gets is Projects and Process. It does not include work items, and I doubt it ever will.  You can see the areas/categories of audit events here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/auditing-events?view=azure-devops